# Como transoformar JSON em array de objetos de uma classe específica, sendo que essa classe possui atributos compostos?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Encontrei o seguinte problema ao tentar transformar uma `String` JSON em lista de objetos.

Tenho a seguinte situação: Possuo uma classe `Response` que possui alguns atributos, entre eles uma lista de "`Post`", sendo que um objeto da classe "`Post`" possui uma lista de objetos da classe "`Anexo`" e preciso gerar essa lista de maneira correta, o que não estou conseguindo.

OBS: utilizando Gson, os outros atributos, que são `String`s, foram preenchidos corretamente, mas quando chegou nessa lista eu tive problemas. Na verdade eu até creio que o Gson tenha feito, mas não consigo visualizar a estrutura.

```java
class Response {
    private List<Post> mPosts;
    // Outros atributos e métodos.
}
```

Possuo o seguinte json para preencher a essa lista de posts

```js
[
  {
    "post_id": "1",
    "post_descricao": "Meu post 1",
    "post_titulo": "Teste",
    "anexos": [
      {
        "anexo_id": "3",
        "anexo_uri": "img-03.png"
      },
      {
        "anexo_id": "4",
        "anexo_uri": "img-04.png"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "post_id": "3",
    "post_descricao": "Meu post 2",
    "post_titulo": "Teste 2",
    " anexos": [
      {
        "anexo_id": "1",
        "anexo_uri": "img-01.png"
      },
      {
        "anexo_id": "2",
        "anexo_uri": "img-02.png"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

E possuo as classes de posts e anexos:

```js
class Post {
    private int id;
    private String titulo;
    private String descricao;
    private List<Anexo> mAnexos;

    // Outros códigos.
}
```

```js
class Anexo {
    private int id;
    private String uri;

    // Outros códigos.
}
```

Como fazer corretamente? Já tentei bastante, Obrigado.

Comment: Edenilton, inclui uma resposta à pergunta. Você conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Devido ao fator tempo, consegui resolver o problema, talvez não tenha sido uma "boa prática" utilizar as conversões manualmente com objetos das classes JSONObject e JSONArray. Meu objetivo era diminuir ao máximo que pudesse as linhas de códigos e agilizar o processo de deserialização. Valeu mesmo! nas próximas vezes vou utilizá-las com calma. Eu tive um problema na hora de utilizar o "Field". Não estava compilando. Pedia para eu alterar as configurações de compilação de projeto: "Change project Compilance and  JRE to 1.8.

Comment: Se tiveres algum projeto configurado utilizando deserializadores de json, peço, por gentileza, que compartilhe comigo. valeu!

Comment: Quanto ao erro, é por que o código está em java 8 mesmo, já inclui uma forma com java antes do 8 também. Quanto a forma mais simples é incluir a anotação `@SerializeName` nos seus atributos mesmo, é o que demanda menos código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partindo do `JSON` apresentando por você e da estrutura de dados também apresentada na pergunta, se usarmos uma abordagem padrão como isto:

```
final Gson gson = new Gson();
final Response response = gson.fromJson(json, Response.class);
```

Ou isto:

```
final Gson gson = new Gson();
final Type type = new TypeToken<List<Post>>() {}.getType();
final List<Post> posts = gson.fromJson(json, type);
response.setMPosts(posts);
```

Não irá funcionar.

No primeiro caso será exibido um erro: `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY`, por que, obviamente o `JSON` não se inicia com um objeto e sim um vetor; já no segundo, todos os atributos estarão nulos ou com seu valor padrão, isto por que o Gson não suporta por padrão a política de nomenclatura adotada nestes seus objetos.

Existem algumas forma de se fazer isto e irei mostrar apenas uma.

1. usar [`@SerializedName`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html) nos atributos com nome fora do padrão suportado;
2. criar um deserializador customizado. Veja aqui como funciona: [**escrevendo um deserializador**](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Writing-a-Deserializer);
3. usar [`FieldNamingStrategy`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/FieldNamingStrategy.html) e definir a estratégia de nomenclatura utilizada nos seus atributos, um `DE-PARA` entre os atributos nos objetos java e os no JSON;
4. renomear os atributos dos seus objetos para refletir alguma abordagem padrão já suportada pelo Gson. Veja neste link: [`FieldNamingPolicy`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/FieldNamingPolicy.html);

Como não foi citado por você qual abordagem já está utilizando para deserializar até a lista e `Post`s, irei mostrar como exemplo a terceira abordagem, criando uma estratégia de nomenclatura própria.

Estou considerando apenas os atributos mostrados na pergunta, caso existam outros que não seguem o padrão você deve considerar na sua implementação.

Para ter esta estratégia própria iremos implementar a interface [`FieldNamingStrategy`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/FieldNamingStrategy.html), a implementação do método [`#translate(Field)`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/FieldNamingStrategy.html#translateName(java.lang.reflect.Field)) ficará mais ou menos assim:

```
final String fieldName = f.getName();
if (fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("mAnexos")) {
    return "anexos";
}

final Class<?> declaringClass = f.getDeclaringClass();
final String className = declaringClass.getSimpleName().toLowerCase();

return className + "_" + fieldName.toLowerCase();
```

O atributo `mAnexos` é o único que não compartilha o mesmo padrão dos outros atributos, então caso seja ele iremos retornar **anexos**, o nome do atributo no `JSON`. Já os outros seguem o mesmo padrão, ou seja, o nome da classe em que estão em caixa baixa separado por um `_` do nome do atributo.

Você pode implementar a estratério de várias forma, um exemplo em Java 8 seria este:

```
final FieldNamingStrategy strategy = (final Field f) -> {
    final String fieldName = f.getName();
    if (fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("mAnexos")) {
        return "anexos";
    }

    final Class<?> declaringClass = f.getDeclaringClass();
    final String className = declaringClass.getSimpleName().toLowerCase();

    return className + "_" + fieldName.toLowerCase();
};
```

Em outras versões do Java você pode implementar desta forma (com classe anônima):

```
final FieldNamingStrategy strategy = new FieldNamingStrategy() {
    public String translateName(final Field f) {
        final String fieldName = f.getName();
        if (fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("mAnexos")) {
            return "anexos";
        }

        final Class<?> declaringClass = f.getDeclaringClass();
        final String className = declaringClass.getSimpleName().toLowerCase();

        return className + "_" + fieldName.toLowerCase();
    }
};
```

Depois de implementarmos a estratégia de nomenclagura, podemos usá-la desta forma:

```
final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingStrategy(strategy).create();

final Type type = new TypeToken<List<Post>>() {}.getType();

final List<Post> posts = gson.fromJson(json, type); // substitua "json" pelo o json que você precisa deserializar
final Response response = new Response();
response.setMPosts(posts);
```

Pode também criar um outro objeto que implemente [`FieldNamingStrategy`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/FieldNamingStrategy.html), fica a seu critério.